# How to load innodb at runtime

Tags: phpmyadmin, storage, innodb, synchronization

I have a database online that does not include innodb as storage engine, neither can I sync the schema with my local database. So as alternative, how do you load or install innodb at runtime?

Comment: "I want a egg but my chicken lays no eggs... i buy a new chicken that does lay eggs."   motto of the story you should go looking for a web hosting provider that will host innodb as storage engine...

Comment: Thanks. Maybe a remote server should do the trick.